# Having trouble exporting multiple MS Access 2010 queries to MS Excel 2010 from one "Form Load" or "Form Open"

Tags: excel, vba, export

I tried this several different ways but it keeps stopping after the first one. I tried adding other forms, form 1 to run one on open, then form 1 opens form 2 which runs one export etc but that didn't work. I tried pausing, `do while not isloaded(next form)` etc but that didn't work.

```
Option Compare Database
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo Err_Form_Load

'I tried 9
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
"AllActiveABC", _
"Y:\Projects\Protocol Folders\AllActiveABC.xls", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
"All-ActiveABC", _
"Y:\Projects\Protocol Folders\AllFilteredABC.xls", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
"All-ActiveABC", _
"Y:\Projects\Protocol Folders\AllFilteredABC.xls", True

'I tried 12 and 12XML
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12xlm, _
"AllActiveABC", _
"Y:\Projects\Protocol Folders\AllActiveABC.xls", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12xlm, _
"AllFilteredABC", _
"Y:\Projects\Protocol Folders\AllFilteredABC.xls", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12xlm, _
"AllActiveABC", _
"Y:\Projects\Protocol Folders\AllActiveABC.xls", True

'I tried it as a function
'see function below the three exports

Call exportData("All-FilteredABC", _
"Y:\Projects\Folders\All-FilteredABC.xlsx")
Call exportData("AllActiveABC", _
"Y:\Projects\Folders\AllActiveABC.xlsx")
Call exportData("AllABC", _
"Y:\Projects\Folders\AllABC.xlsx")


Function exportData(queryName As String, strSaveFileName As String)

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, queryName, strSaveFileName, True 

End Function
```

No luck. I am so confused by all the things I've tried and the different outcomes I've had like, creating a new blank sheet in the existing workbook but with an _1 at the end, stopping after one export, exporting them all but all blank.

Answer (score 0):

try entering the command DoEvents after each DoCmd. to allow everything to catch up

ie

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
"AllActiveABC", _
"Y:\Projects\Protocol Folders\AllActiveABC.xls", True

DoEvents